# how can I write parentheses for matrix exactly like in the picture?

Tags: matrices

how can I write parentheses for matrix exactly like in the picture?

[image]

[image]

[image]  [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean with that font? In that case, if you have you could show a little more specimen of it (though I'll be of no help, I'm horrible at recognising fonts -- I only know a few).

Comment: @Skillmon, maybe with special font, maybe with special package, no idea, I put more agian, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need `stix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,stix}

\begin{document}

\[
\big\lgroup\,\begin{matrix}
    3 &  \phantom{-}2\\
    3 & -2
\end{matrix}\,\big\rgroup
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome, many thanks